# Взаимодействие с консолью

Tags: python, процесс

Задача запутить консольную программу и иметь возможность работать с ней.
То есть написать скрипт открывающий вторым процессом допустим console_program.exe с возможностью вписывать команды уже в эту программу.

Может через псевдокод будет яснее.

```
import magiccmdapi

program = magiccmdapi.run("program.exe")
program.execute("command1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взаимодействие с консольными программами рекомендуется через класс Popen

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["program.exe"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as proc:
    proc.stdin.write('command1')
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```